# How to "echo" or show pictures from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, echo

I'm trying to use the below code to reflect different pictures of the moon into an HTML doc. Of course i've added the Jquery and Javascript tags.

I've been looking at this for hours and trying different things but **I can't find out what to put into HTML code that will actually show or echo the pictures**.

What should I put into the "moonImage.src = "pix/moon" + truncPhase + ".png";" part of the code? I don't understand how to essentially echo the photos. Help please?:

```
// Image max size
var IMAGE_MAX_SIZE = 196;

// Records whether or not the gadget is expanded
var poppedOut = false;

function onOpen() {
  // Check once every 30 minutes
  view.setInterval(onTimer, 30 * 60 * 1000);
  // Initialize the gadget
  onTimer();
}

// Called when the timer goes off
function onTimer() {
  // Compute the moon phase each time timer is called
  var cal = new Date();
  // Base the computation off of UTC time, to the nearest hour
  var phase = computeMoonPhase(cal.getUTCFullYear(), 
                               cal.getUTCMonth() + 1,
                               cal.getUTCDate(),
                               cal.getUTCHours());
  var truncPhase = Math.floor(phase) % 30;

  // Find the text description of the current phase
  var desc;
  if (truncPhase === 0) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_NEW;
  } else if (truncPhase == 7) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_FIRST_QUARTER;
  } else if (truncPhase == 15) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_FULL;
  } else if (truncPhase == 23) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_THIRD_QUARTER;
  } else if (truncPhase > 0 && phase < 7) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_WAXING_CRESCENT;
  } else if (truncPhase > 7 && phase < 15) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_WAXING_GIBBOUS;
  } else if (truncPhase > 15 && phase < 23) {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_WANING_GIBBOUS;
  } else {
    desc = STRING_MOON_DESC_WANING_CRESCENT;
  }

  // Set the image and text component appropriately
  moonImage.src = "pix/moon" + truncPhase + ".png";
  moonImage.tooltip = (Math.floor(phase * 100) / 100) + " " + STRING_DAYS_OLD;
  phaseAge.innerText = STRING_MOON_AGE_PREFIX + " " + moonImage.tooltip +
                       "\n" +
                       desc;
}

// Called when view is resized (recompute constituent basicElement sizes and
// locations)
function resizeView() {
  setDimensions(event.width, event.height);
}

// Open the browser whenever a user double clicks (expanded or collapsed)
function onDblClick() {
 var obj = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
 obj.Open("http://stardate.org/nightsky/moon/");
}

// Show date age in title, when gadget is minimized
function onMinimize() {
  view.caption = STRING_MOON_SHORT + " - " + moonImage.tooltip;
}

// Only show the textual part (details) when popped out
function onPopout() {
  poppedOut = true;
  phaseAge.visible = true;
}

// Hide the textual part in restored mode, show regular title, and reset
// dimensions
function onRestore() {
  view.caption = GADGET_NAME;
  phaseAge.visible = false;
  //moonImage.enabled = true;
  poppedOut = false;
  setDimensions(view.width, view.height);
}

// Called whenever the sizes and/or locations of basicElements need to change
function setDimensions(width, height) {
  // Image is square, constrained by smallest dimension
  var sz = Math.min(width, height);

  // Make the image almost as large as the sz
  moonImage.width = Math.min(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE, sz * 0.9);
  moonImage.height = Math.min(IMAGE_MAX_SIZE, sz * 0.9);

  if (poppedOut) {
    // Align image on left, and set text location
    moonImage.x = 0;
    phaseAge.x = moonImage.width + 5;
    phaseAge.y = (height - phaseAge.height) / 2;
  } else {
    // Center image horizontally
    moonImage.x = (width - moonImage.width) * 0.5;
  }

  // Always center image vertically
  moonImage.y = (height - moonImage.height) * 0.5;
}

// Compute the moon phase.
// Code is based upon Bradley E. Schaefer''s well-known moon phase algorithm.
function computeMoonPhase(year, month, day, hours) {
  var MOON_PHASE_LENGTH = 29.530588853;

  // Convert the year into the format expected by the algorithm
  var transformedYear = year - Math.floor((12 - month) / 10);

  // Convert the month into the format expected by the algorithm
  var transformedMonth = month + 9;
  if (transformedMonth >= 12) {
    transformedMonth = transformedMonth - 12;
  }

  // Logic to compute moon phase as a fraction between 0 and 1
  var term1 = Math.floor(365.25 * (transformedYear + 4712));
  var term2 = Math.floor(30.6 * transformedMonth + 0.5);
  var term3 = Math.floor(Math.floor((transformedYear / 100) + 49) * 0.75) - 38;
  var intermediate = term1 + term2 + (day + (hours - 1) / 24) + 59;
  if (intermediate > 2299160) {
    intermediate = intermediate - term3;
  }
  var normalizedPhase = (intermediate - 2451550.1) / MOON_PHASE_LENGTH;
  normalizedPhase = normalizedPhase - Math.floor(normalizedPhase);
  if (normalizedPhase < 0) {
    normalizedPhase = normalizedPhase + 1;
  }

  // Return the result as a value between 0 and MOON_PHASE_LENGTH
  return normalizedPhase * MOON_PHASE_LENGTH;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html> 
    <head><title>Kendrick Moon</title> 
        <script src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/ (etc.) 
        <script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>; 
        <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <head> 
    <body> 
        <div><img src=""/> </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: where is `moonImage` defined. How is your code connected to the web document and can you provide some HTML code too?

Comment: @Luke Thanks for the prompt response. Actually i'm just using a test image to try and get it working. But thats the core of question: how do I connect this code to the html. Here's what I have for html so far: "<html>
<head>
 <title>Kendrick Moon</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head>
<body>
 <div>
<img src=""/>
 </div>


</body>
</html>"

Comment: Just so you're aware, `ActiveXObject` only works in IE. And, for your purpose, using a link is a better way to go (the code you're using just opens a link to the specified URL via the default browser, something a link would more easily do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, well thats then easy.

first of all, you might want to check out jquery. with jquery it would be something like this.

```
<img src="" id="my_image" />
```

in javascript then (with jquery)

```
// the `myLinkToImage` is hopefully the variable of your path
$("#my_image").attr("src", myLinkToImage);
```

as you can see I´m using `#`. That is a typical jQuery Selector. You might check out more of them [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

in javascript without jquery

```
document.getElementById("my_image").src = myLinkToImage;
```

Comment: Luke thank you i'll try that. Pardon my ignorance but, does this mean I don't have to add anything to the html? And where in the javascript I showed you should I add that javascript or jquery? Lmk thanks..

Comment: Thanks Luke I will try that and close this out when I complete it. Cheers.